# Solution to $y''-2y'+y=\frac{e^x}{x^2+1}$ using variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution to this differential equation using the method of variation of parameters. $$y''-2y'+y=\frac{e^x}{x^2+1}$$

I do not understand this problem at all. Can someone please help me?

Comment: I think the original post has two odes.

Comment: It looked like a copy from a book, so he was only interested in the second one. Regards

Answer (score 4):

We are asked to solve this using [*Variation of Parameters (VoP)*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VariationofParameters.html), given:

$$\tag 1 y''-2y' + y = \dfrac{e^x}{x^2+1}$$

**Step 1**

Find the homogenous solution to $(1)$, so we have:

$$\tag 2 y''-2y' + y = 0$$

This yields:

$$y_h = c_1 e^x + c_2 xe^x$$

**Step 2**

We are now going to make use of VoP, so we set: $y_1 = e^x$ and $y_2 = xe^x$ from $y_h$ and $f = \dfrac{e^x}{x^2+1}$ from $(1)$.

We calculate the Wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$, yielding $W(e^x, xe^x) = e^{2x}$.

Using VoP, we have:

$\displaystyle u_1 = \int \dfrac{-y_2 f}{W(e^x, x e^x)} dx = -\int \dfrac{x}{x^2+1} dx = -\dfrac{1}{2} \ln (x^2+1)$

$\displaystyle u_2 = \int \dfrac{y_1 f}{W(e^x, x e^x)} dx = \int \dfrac{1}{x^2+1} dx = \tan^{-1} x$

Now, $y_p$ is given by:

$$y_p = y_1 u_1 + y_2 u_2 = -e^x\left(\dfrac{1}{2} \ln (x^2+1)\right) + xe^x  \tan^{-1} x $$

**Step 3**

Our final solution is given by:

$$y(x) = y_h(x) + y_p(x) = c_1e^x + c_2 xe^x -e^x\left(\dfrac{1}{2} \ln (x^2+1)\right) + xe^x \tan^{-1} x$$

Comment: Well done! $+1$

Comment: Yes, all went well, as planned (so I'm done with the daily day-long visits). Now, I'll just have some outpatient (normal appointments - meaning short - 30 minute) appointments for follow up.